# How to externally trigger d3 events

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 selection upon which I have defined event callbacks.

```
var obj = d3.select("#kk").on("mouseleave",function(){
              console.log("mouse leave");       
          });
```

How can I trigger the event externally? Is there something like:

```
obj.mouseleave(); // actuall mouse leave function calling
```

If there is, and if I select the object without referring to `obj`, will the trigger still work?

As in:

```
var newObje=d3.select("#kk");
newObje.mouseleave(); //will this trigger the previously defined instructions
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are already on D3 **v4**, you can use [`selection.dispatch()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_dispatch) which was specifically designed to do exactly what you are looking for:

> *[#](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_dispatch)* *selection*.**dispatch**(*type*[, *parameters*]) <>
>
> Dispatches a [custom event](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#interface-customevent) of the specified *type* to each selected element, in order.

This was included in v4 as a result of the issue ["Ability to trigger event handlers manually. #100"](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/100).

Furthermore, the method will enable you to dispatch events of the same type to all elements contained in the selection. The implementation of that method looks similar to the approach the other answerers took by putting `event.dispatch()` to use, but will make your life somewhat easier. The following snippet has a listener for each individual circle, which may all be triggered by the button at once.

```js
var circles = d3.select("svg").selectAll("circle")
  .data(d3.range(5))
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return 60 * i + 20; })
    .attr("cy", "30")
    .attr("r", "20").attr("fill", "blue")
    .on("mouseleave",function(){
      d3.select(this)
        .attr("fill", "red")
        .transition().duration(1000)
        .attr("fill", "blue");
    });

d3.select("#btn")
  .on("click", function() {
    circles.dispatch("mouseleave");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<svg width="400" height="70"></svg>

<button id="btn">Dispatch mouseleave to all circles</button>
```

Comment: I wanted to use selection.dispatch to trigger drag events but did not manage to do so. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60847359/how-to-programmatically-trigger-drag-events-with-d3-js

Comment: Same here, Stefan - did you maybe find a way to fix it? I can trigger all events whose handlers are not defined inside the call() function, but since drag is called inside call(), that seems to be the issue :-/

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you don't need d3 to trigger the event, vanilla javascript is enough for that. You simply need to use the [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) function.

Here is an example of how you would do it (from a button for example).

I added both the d3.select way and the plain JS way, both should work fine.

```js
d3.select("#kk").on("mouseleave",function(){
  console.log("mouseleave");
});

var button = document.getElementById('trigger-event');
button.onclick = function() {
  var evt = new MouseEvent("mouseleave");
  
  // The way to dispatch the event using d3
  d3.select('#kk').node().dispatchEvent(evt);
  
  // The way to dispatch it with plain JS
  document.getElementById('kk').dispatchEvent(evt);
};
```

```css
#kk {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="kk">
  
</div>


<button id="trigger-event">trigger event</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

The following will trigger the `mouseleave` event on the elements via `dispatchEvent()`.

```
  var event = document.createEvent('Event');
  event.initEvent('mouseleave', true, true);

  d3.selectAll("circle").node().dispatchEvent(event);
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eBYvVN (I've added a button at the bottom to trigger it.  The mouseleave event is attached to the circles)

Answer (score 1):

You can make one constant function for mouseleave and call it on mouse leave or externally as well like this :

```
function mouseleave(){            // Main mouse leave function.
     console.log('inside mouseleave function.');    
}



var obj = d3.select("#kk").on("mouseleave",function(){ // It will call on actual mouse leave event
                  console.log("mouseleave");
                  mouseleave();
              });

    mouseleave(); // call it externally when ever you want.
```

Comment: My application has a complex structure of backbone models and the callback function is actually stored in a nested collection and the trigger is made by a totally different one and I don't wish to make a global function.