# How to programmatically trigger drag events with d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, events, drag-and-drop

I wrote some code that uses a drag event for svg elements. The code works fine and I would like to write some tests for it. Instead of manually moving my mouse by hand I would like to programmatically trigger the `dragstart` and `drag` events with [selection.dispatch](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_dispatch):

```
     svgSelection.dispatch('dragstart',{bubbles:true});
     svgSelection.dispatch('drag',{bubbles:true});
```

However, the events do not seem to be fired. Maybe I use the wrong event keys or need to include some additional option?

I also tried to use following variants that did not help:

```
svgElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('drag', {bubbles:true}));

svgSelection.dispatch('mousedown.drag',{bubbles:true});
```

If I try

```
svgElement.on('mousedown.drag')()
```

I get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ctrlKey' of null
    at defaultFilter (drag.js?009f:10)
    at mousedowned (drag.js?009f:51)
```

What is the right way to trigger the events 'start' and 'drag' used in following code?

```
    let offset = [0,0];
    let drag = d3.drag()
        .on('start', () => this.__dragStarted(d3, svgSelection, offset))
        .on('drag', ()=> this.__dragged(d3, svgSelection, offset));
    svgSelection.call(drag);
```

My test example:

```
it('enableDragAndDrop', ()=>{
     let element = document.createElement('svg');
     let svgSelection = d3.select(element);

     spyOn(sut, '__dragStarted');
     spyOn(sut, '__dragged');

     sut.enableDragAndDrop(svgSelection);
     svgSelection.dispatch('dragstart',{bubbles:true});
     svgSelection.dispatch('drag',{bubbles:true});

     expect(sut.__dragStarted).toHaveBeenCalled();
     expect(sut.__dragged).toHaveBeenCalled();

});
```

My code example:

```
enableDragAndDrop(svgSelection){
    let offset = [0,0];
    let drag = d3.drag()
        .on('start', () => this.__dragStarted(d3, svgSelection, offset))
        .on('drag', ()=> this.__dragged(d3, svgSelection, offset));
    svgSelection.call(drag);
}

__dragStarted(d3, svgSelection, offset){
    if(!svgSelection.attr('transform')){
        svgSelection.attr('transform','translate(0,0)');
    }

    let transform = svgSelection.attr('transform');
    let translate = this.__extractTranslate(transform);
    offset[0] = translate[0] - d3.event.x;
    offset[1] = translate[1] - d3.event.y;
}

__dragged(d3, svgSelection, offset){

    let x = d3.event.x + offset[0];
    let y = d3.event.y + offset[1];
    svgSelection
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x + ', ' + y + ')');
}

__extractTranslate(transformString){
    let stripped = transformString;
    stripped = stripped.replace('translate(','');
    stripped = stripped.replace(')','');
    let numberStrings = stripped.split(',');
    return numberStrings.map(numberString=>parseFloat(numberString));
}
```

Related questions:

[How to externally trigger d3 events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40415144/how-to-externally-trigger-d3-events)

[How to trigger event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

[dataTransfer is null when creating drag event programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20867245/datatransfer-is-null-when-creating-drag-event-programmatically)

Comment: Hey Stefa, did you ever get this to run and if so, how? Struggling with it for the past few days..

Comment: In terms of testing, mocking d3 was the solution for me, see answer below. For an example on drag & drop see line 134 in https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/treezjs/blob/master/src/result/sankey/nodes.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a work around that partially mocks d3 with jest:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';

jest.mock('d3', ()=>{

    let wrappedD3 = jest.requireActual('d3');

    var d3Mock = {
        drag: undefined,
        event: wrappedD3.event,
        select: wrappedD3.select,
        __passedEventHandlers: []
    };

    d3Mock.drag = ()=>{
        let dragMock = {
            apply: ()=>{}
        };
        dragMock.on = (event, eventHandler)=>{
                d3Mock.__passedEventHandlers.push(eventHandler);
                return dragMock;
        }
        return dragMock;
    };

    return d3Mock;

});
```

Example usage in test:

```
it('enableDragAndDrop', ()=>{
     let element = document.createElement('svg');
     document.body.appendChild(element);

     let svgSelection = d3.select(element);   

     sut.enableDragAndDrop(svgSelection);

     spyOn(sut, '__dragStarted');
     let dragStartedHandler = d3.__passedEventHandlers[0];
     dragStartedHandler();
     expect(sut.__dragStarted).toHaveBeenCalled();

     spyOn(sut, '__dragged');
     let draggedHandler = d3.__passedEventHandlers[1];
     draggedHandler();
     expect(sut.__dragged).toHaveBeenCalled();

});
```